# SSIS can't create Destination flat file

Tags: ssis, derived-column

I have a package where I have an input file that has a header line

TI,2

and detail line(s) that look like this

YP,302,,0000000000000061.00,20170714,CHK #9999,R04,9999

I have to do some processing on the detail lines. The file name is in a variable called User::FileName

In my Data Flow I have a conditional split where I shoot the Header Record to a path where I create a file with just the header record (it doesn't change).

I process all of the detail records. I have to go into SQL to do this and write out the results into a comma delimited flat file with the same name as the input file (using the variable).

So now I have a Header file with a fixed name and a detail file with the name in a variable. I need to combine these. I am trying to create a .BAT that that says

copy /y /d /b header.txt + User::FileName  User::Filename (with the proper values substituted for the variable) and then execute this with an Execute Process task.

I am doing this with a Data Flow Task. The source is a Flat file (copy.bat) that contains 2 columns. Column 0 has copy /y /d /b. I have a derived column called Rest_of_Copy that has header.txt + User::FileName + " " + User::Filename

On the output file Destination I also have 2 columns. I am mapping Column 0 (the copy /y /d /b) to column 0 on the output file and The Derived Column Rest_of_Copy (which should contain the results of header.txt + User::FileName + " " + User::Filename). The Connection Manager for the Destination File is Copyout.bat

When I run the package Copyout.bat is empty.

I can't figure out why. Can anybody help?

Comment: When you run the package in Visual Studio, do you see rows flowing to the destination?   Can you add a screenshot of this?

Comment: I get the green check marks, but no records flowing. How do I give you a screen shot?

Comment: Take a screen shot and post it to imgur or some similar image posting site, and add the link to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to do it. I wrote out the 2 files to fixed names, so the COPY command was fixed, and then renamed the output file to the SSIS variable using a File System task.

Thanks,

Dick